# Is it forbidden to count Jewish people without uttering any words?

Tags: halacha, number, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, speech-talking

Related: [Am I allowed to count people?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/176/am-i-allowed-to-count-people)

[We are not allowed to count Jewish people](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/188/8775). But one can count other objects to represent the people and one can also speak the words of a possuk where the number of words therein is known.

I understand from this that counting by looking at the people and saying words  out loud “one, two, three etc.” is what is forbidden.

Is it forbidden to look at the people and count them **without uttering any words** (but so-to-speak saying them in one's head)?

Comment: Counting used to be done by donating a half sheqel. Did this involve any words? If it did not, then the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [OU](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/practical-halacha/prohibition-counting-jewish-people/) quotes "the Kaf Hachaim (13:10) writes that one is permitted to count Jewish People in one’s mind (b’machshava), as long as he does not count them audibly." This is referring to the [Kaf HaChaim Palagi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haim_Palachi) ([13:10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53455&st=&pgnum=164)) who writes:

> לא ימנה המנין לגולגולת לא בלשון לעז ולא בשאר לשונות ואפילו בלשון הקודש, אלא באומדנא ובמחשבה למראה עיניו, ולא יהיה רומז באצבעותיו.‏
>
> One should not count the quorum by heads not in a foreign language nor in the Holy Tongue, rather by estimation and thought according to what he sees, and he should not hint with his fingers.

Answer (score 3):

Yoma 22b

> תנא הוציאו אצבעותיכם למנין ונימנינהו לדידהו מסייע ליה לרבי יצחק דאמר רבי יצחק אסור למנות את ישראל אפילו לדבר מצוה דכתיב (שמואל א יא) ויפקדם בבזק מתקיף לה רב אשי ממאי דהאי בזק לישנא דמיבזק הוא ודילמא שמא דמתא הוא כדכתיב (שופטים א) וימצאו אדני בזק אלא מהכא (שמואל א טו) וישמע שאול את העם ויפקדם בטלאים אמר רבי אלעזר  **כל המונה את ישראל עובר בלאו**   שנאמר (הושע ב) והיה מספר בני ישראל **כחול הים אשר לא ימד** רב נחמן בר יצחק אמר  עובר בשני לאוין שנאמר לא ימד ולא יספר אמר רבי שמואל בר נחמני ר' יונתן רמי כתיב והיה מספר בני ישראל כחול הים וכתיב אשר לא ימד ולא יספר לא קשיא כאן בזמן שישראל עושין רצונו של מקום כאן בזמן שאין עושין רצונו של מקום רבי אמר משום אבא יוסי בן דוסתאי לא קשיא כאן בידי אדם כאן בידי שמים

Gemara reports two opinions, both based on a verse in Hoshea. Anyway it is prohibited to count persons, we can count an object for each person and to know how many persos there is (three examples in Gemara: fingers, pieces of terracotta,  lambs)

The prohibition is reported in Rambam Avoda, Tmidin, 4, 4

The problem seems to be the fact that the counted thing is a person, not the words being pronounced.

Comment: You bring no evidence about any difference between pronouncing the words or thinking. (not my downvote).

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok, you are right, I just want to show that the gemara's problem is that a number of men is the result, not a pronounciation of count.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I see what you mean. Ideally, I would like to see a more explicit answer.