# When is it halachically prohibited to count Jews?

Tags: number

Half Shekalim were used to take a census of Jews in the desert. When counting Jews to form a minyan, people use a verse or some other method to count rather than using direct numbers.

Under what criteria is it prohibited to count Jews directly? Is it at all times or only for *davar mitzvah*? E.g., at a party, can I count Jews for table seating or for attendance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magen Avraham, OC 156:2 (in the middle of DH Mitzvah), infers that it is always forbidden, even for a Mitzvah:

> אסור למנות ישראל אפילו אינו מכוון למנות רק להטיל גורל אפילו לדבר מצוה אלא מוציאין אצבעותיהם ומונין אצבעותיהם (יומא כב).
>
> It is forbidden to count Jews, even if he doesn’t intend to count, only to take a lottery, even for a Mitzvah. Rather, they stick out their fingers and count their fingers (Yoma 22).

Comment: Interestingly, he doesn't mention the pasuk method. I'm probably going to ask a follow up question. Thanks for the source.