# Can Jews be counted if each person says his / her number?

Tags: number

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100159/5275) indicates that it is always forbidden to count Jews directly.

However, can one count them if each person says his / her number? E.g. - when I was in camp, the counselor assigned us a number prior to boarding the bus when we went on a trip. Before we left, the counselor says, "Count off!". Each person shouts his / her number.

Is that method permissible, or is it the same as someone taking a direct count because he hears a specific number. In other words, to prevent counting does that mean that one can't use numbers at all regardless of whether he counts or the people say a number?

Comment: Why should there be a difference between people providing fingers or people providing numbers?

Comment: [Am I on-topic?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/9682)

Comment: @DonielF The issue may be based on a technicality of what "counting" and "numbers" mean. You're allowed to count, but not by directly using the number. So my question focuses on that term "number". Does it matter if you say the number or the people you are counting say it?

Comment: How would you give them numbers in the first place? You would have to count everyone first..

Comment: Perhaps there's a fine definition between counting and finding the total. But, I understand your question. Have to think about it.